# What is the use of = sign (single) in a condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, assignment-operator

I had read in some articles that in some languages, like in JavaScript, assignment operators can be used in conditional statements. I want to know what is the logic behind that operation? As far as I know, only comparison operators are allowed in condition checking statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any expression is allowed in a condition checking statement. If the value of the expression isn't boolean, then it will be converted to boolean to determine what the statement should do.

You can for example use a number in an `if` statement:

```
if (1) { ... }
```

Any non-zero number will be converted to `true`.

In Javascript an assignment is also an expression, i.e. it has a value. The value of the expression is the same value that was assigned to the variable.

So, you can use an assignment expression in a condition checking statement, and the value of the expression is converted to boolean if needed:

```
if (x = 1) { ... }
```

Using an assignment in an condition checking statement can be useful, if the value that you assign should be used to control what happens. If you for example have a function that returns different values for the first calls, then a `null` when there are no more values, you can use that in a loop:

```
while (line = getLine()) {
  document.write(line);
}
```

You can of couse do that with the assignment separated from the logic, but then the code gets more complicated:

```
while (true) {
  line = getLine();
  if (line == null) break;
  document.write(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (and many other languages), when a value is assigned to a variable, the value "returned" is the value that was assigned to a variable. As such, such a statement can be used in a condition with any assigned value being evaluated in the standard way.

For example:

```
var y = 0;
if(x = y){
    alert("Y(and thus X) is Truthy");
}
else{
    alert("Y(and thus X) is Falsy");
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) But I still don't get it. Here we're assigning a value, not comparing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors that combine to give this effect:

- in many languages, including JavaScript, an expression of the form `left = right` evaluates to the new `left`. For example, `a = b = c = 0` sets all of `a`, `b`, and `c` to zero.
- in many languages, including JavaScript, a wide variety of values can be used as conditional expressions. `if(7)` is equivalent to `if(true)`; so `if(a = 7)` is equivalent to `a = 7; if(true)` rather than to the presumably-intended `if(a == 7)`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation :) So these types of evaluations can be done only in the case of a zero and nonzero comparison, right??

Comment: @BlackPanda: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question. In JavaScript, *any* value can be used as a conditional expression; `if({})` means `if(true)`, `if(new Object())` means `if(true)`, `if("")` means `if(false)`, `if(null)` means `if(false)`, and so on. So this issue can affect *any* comparison; if you accidentally type `if(... = ...)` instead of `if(... == ...)`, that will *never* give you an error -- it just won't do what you want.

Comment: @BlackPanda: Actually, wait, I think I see your confusion. To clarify: there is *no logic* in `if (a = b)`. It's not an intentional feature of the language. It's just that the assignment expression `a = b` evaluates to a value, and `if (...)` can use any value at all; so `if (a = b) { ... }` ends up being legal code (meaning the same as `a = b; if (a) { ... }`), even though it's almost never what you want. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, very clearly. :) Thanks for pointing out that it's not a intentional feature of the language. But now my doubts extend this question's scope. :p Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value with **=** returns that value. You can use it to make an assignment while testing if the outcome is truthy or falsey (null, 0, "" undefined, NaN, false)

```
if (myVar = myArgument) ...
//same as:
// myVar=myArgument;
// if (myArgument) ...
```

This assigns myArgument to myVar while testing myArgument. Another more specific example:

```
If (myVar = 3+2) ...
// same as:
// myVar=3+2;
// if (5) ...
```

The benefit is more compact, terse code, sometimes at the expense of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This could be used to make a condition check and also use the `value` after it, without writing more lines.

```
if (value = someFunction()) {
    ...
}
```

This is valid syntax, though highly discouraged. In quite a few languages this is explicitely forbidden, but some languages also does not make this rule (e.g. C).

Comment: So here, either value is a boolean variable or we are just checking whether value is zero or a nonzero value, right??

Comment: We are checking if the return value is *truthy*: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/