# Condition is not taken into account in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I made a form with HTML on Symfony. With JavaScript, I am adding a new input every time I click on the button with the id addwishedlanguage. From the first click on the button, a new button appears, the one with the following id: removewishedlanguage. This one allows me to remove inputs that have been added. I am trying to hide this button when I end up to have one input left (the initial one). So I created idcounter in order to be aware when there is only one input left and I created the following condition: idcounter = 1. But the problem is that this condition is not taken into account. My button is hidden too soon from the first time I click on it.

What did I miss?

```
var idcounter = 1;
var id = "user_wishedlanguages" + idcounter;

document.getElementById("addwishedlanguage").onclick = function() {
    console.log(idcounter)
    const wishedlanguageselect = document.getElementById("user_wishedlanguages");
    const newwishedlanguageselect = wishedlanguageselect.cloneNode(true);
    newwishedlanguageselect.id = id;
    document.querySelector('.wishedlanguagelist').appendChild(newwishedlanguageselect);
    document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").style.display = "initial";
    idcounter++
}

document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").onclick = function() {
    console.log(idcounter)
    idcounter--
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
    if(idcounter = 1) {
        document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: You used the [assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) instead of [comparing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) the values.

Comment: You say "with the class addwishedlanguage", but then you use `getElementById("addwishedlanguage")` to get the element, which of course would only work with a (single) button with an id of "addwishedlanguage". Note that your variable `id` is not updated when you change the value of `idcounter`; the value remains "user_wishedlanugages1".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of = sign (single) in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261072/what-is-the-use-of-sign-single-in-a-condition)

Comment: Yes, I did it on purpose so that I have new ids on new inputs. I just confused class and id in the statement.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That was the problem. Thank you !